# JQuery toggleClass and slideToggle - not behaving correctly for toggleClass

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's what I actually want to happen:

Show the div first when the page loads
When the user clicks on the "up arrow", the arrow switches to a "down arrow" and hides the div.  When the user clicks on the "down arrow", the div is then displayed.

However, while I do have the page correctly displaying the div when the page loads, When the user clicks on the "up arrow", it remains up until the user clicks on it again.

I have the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

   $('.show_hide').click(function(){
      $(".slidingDiv").slideToggle('slow',function() {
         $('#arrow-down1').toggleClass('arrow-down1', $(this).is(':visible')); /* display the down arrow */
         $('#arrow-down2').toggleClass('arrow-down2', $(this).is(':visible')); /* display the down arrow */
         $('#arrow-up1').toggleClass('showhide', $(this).is(':visible')); /* hides the up arrow */
         $('#arrow-up2').toggleClass('showhide', $(this).is(':visible'));    /* hides the up arrow */           

   }); /* slidingDiv Toggle */      
  }); /* show_hide click function */
});
```

You can see this at http://jsfiddle.net/jdYX6/7/

Thanks!

Comment: Hm, You're creating something terribly complicated both your CSS and jQ for something that is actually terribly simple.

Comment: I agree with roXon, it looks like that whole arrow thing you have going on there is more complicated than it need be, and is causing you to have a lot of convoluted logic to deal with it. Whats the purpose of building it with a lot of smaller divs? So only the grey part is clickable? So its not img-dependant?

Comment: also note, `transform: rotate()` is not supported in IE8 (so you might as well use jQuery 2.0 rather than 1.9 if you're ok with that)

Comment: Not supporting IE actually.  And yes, so that it's not img-dependent.  The grey part is clickable.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is too complex and it's confusing the task.

Here's a version that I believe achieves the desired effect:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="handle" class="down">v</a>
<div id="dialog" class="open">
    <p>Lorem Ipsem...</p>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#handle").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).toggleClass("up down");
        $("#dialog").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

CSS

```
a#handle {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 3em;
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
a:active, a:focus {
    outline-style: none;
}
a.up {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
div#dialog {
    background-color: #eef;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    padding: 2em;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/GamDn/2/